# Inserting an add button after a field_reference

Tags: atk4

I would like to modify the form class so for every field_reference it adds a button `+` so users are able to directly insert a new element into that referenced table.

i.e: I'm completing a customer form and cannot found his city in the list. I just click an the `+` and the city form appears and let me insert the correct city.

I think I have to try by modifying atk4/lib/Controller/MVCForm.php around

`if($field instanceof Field_Reference || $field_type=='reference') {
            $form_field->setModel($field->getModel());
}`

But maybe it's something to add in atk4/lib/field/Reference.php directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this one:
https://github.com/atk4/autocomplete/blob/master/lib/Form/Field/Plus.php

It's not exactly what you're asking for, but this field type has implemented "plus" behavior. You can at least get some ideas from there if not using autocomplete field

Comment: Am I limited in the number of VirtualPages inside others ? Now I've got a "plus" button for adding a city and in the city form a "plus" button to add a country. But this time I get a StopInit Exception... I tried to remove the throw and a new virtualpage opens but the form is based on the city model and not country

Comment: It's not a good idea to have VirtualPage inside VirtualPage. It should work, but as far as I remember doing that - it didn't work out nicely. I used some hacks like $api->stickyForget() calls and so on. It'll be better if you rethink your UI and use only one level deep VPage. Also I guess that'll be more user friendly :)